# unix command to see the last run command on command line

Tags: unix, ksh

what is the command to see the previously executed command that was run on the command line
?

Answer (score 12):

use the `history` command.

`history -1` will display only the last command. Otherwise, `history` will list the last 16 commands (for plain `ksh`, but this may differ with other korn-compatible shells).

You can also use the `fc` builtin command if you are using plain `ksh` (command options are described in the [man page](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ksh++NetBSD-current)).

Comment: history lists the last 500 commands for me.  (But I'm on OS X.)

Comment: then, you are probably using `bash` and not `ksh`.

Comment: I did the test on MacOSX 10.5.8: `ksh`'s history displays only 16 entries, as osx's `man ksh` says (search for "16" in the man page). `bash`'s history displays the whole `$HISTFILE`. (for you, 500 as you probably have `$HISTFILESIZE` set to 500.

Comment: And regarding bash's history command: `alias h='history $((LINES - 1))'` is good to view recent history without completely destroying the scrollback.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/17565-ksh-how-make-up-arrow-recall-command-history.html), you can use the **Up Arrow** key once you add the following lines to the bottom of your .kshrc file in your $HOME directory:

```
set -o emacs
alias __A=$(print '\0020') # ^P = up = previous command
alias __B=$(print '\0016') # ^N = down = next command
alias __C=$(print '\0006') # ^F = right = forward a character
alias __D=$(print '\0002') # ^B = left = back a character
alias __H=$(print '\0001') # ^A = home = beginning of line
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your shell. If you want to *run* the last command, in bash for example, you can type `!!`.

See [this page](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114036) for more info.

**EDIT**

Oh well, now I noticed that you had tagged your post ksh. Sorry about that. I'll leave this answer here anyway. Maybe it helps someone someday :)